# How to get an ID from the collection in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-collection

I am writing one database query it's returning the matching record that's stored in one variable called $store,i want to get the id of the particular record which is stored in the $store variable.

```
$store=DB::table('books')->where('bookName','dummy')->get();
```

books migration table structure

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('bookName');  //it's uniqe
$table->int('price');
```

what i am trying is when i try to get the id of a particular book based on $store `[$store->id]`variable it's throwing an error  called

`Propert id doesnot exist on collection instance`

Answer (score 1):

it's showing clearly `collection` so you have to call the following way

```
$store[0]->id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$store=DB::table('books')->where('bookName','dummy')->get();
foreach($store as $str){
   echo $id = $str->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the id, the common way will be use select.
`Model::select('id')->get();`

And in the view you can iterate the ModelCollection and use `$item->id` or '$item['id']'

Answer (score 0):

foreaxample, getting first book id with specific price:

```
$id = $store->where('price', 100)->first()->id;
```